# dynamic text and links with jCanvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, jcanvas

I have a canvas and I use jCanva (http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs.php?p=layers)s to create circles with events.

I want that every circle will have text (for mouseover event) and id (for click event).
The problem is that the events are dynamic, and the "i" is always the last i (data.length) so all the circles get the same values...
How can I solve it?

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var id = data[i][0];
                var text = data[i][2];

                $("#mapCanvas").drawArc({
                    layer: true,
                    fillStyle: "yellow",
                    strokeStyle: "#000",
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    x: Math.random() * c.clientWidth,
                    y: Math.random() * c.clientHeight,
                    radius: 6,
                    click: function (layer) {
                        window.open("Edit/" + id);
                    },
                    mouseover: function (layer) {
                       $("canvas")
                       .addLayer({
                            method: "drawRect",
                            name: "BackgroundLabel",
                            group: "ItemLabel",
                            fillStyle: "#FFFFD4",
                            x: layer.x + 10,
                            y: layer.y - 15,
                            width: 100,
                            height: 20
                       })
                       .drawLayers();

                       $("#mapCanvas").drawText({
                        layer: true,
                        fillStyle: "white",
                        strokeWidth: 0,
                        x: layer.x + 10,
                        y: layer.y - 10,
                        font: "14pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif",
                        text: text
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Check if you can push the id/name to the layer object that you get as argument in the event handler, or you can write it like that:
`
click: (function () {
  return function(id){
   window.open("Edit/" + id);
  }
})();
`
To create different scope for each drawing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it - I created a sepereate function "drawOneCircle" that gets the vars and use them.
"drawOneCircle" is now contains the content of the original "for" loop.

```
           for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var id = data[i][0];
                var text = data[i][2];
                drawOneCircle(c, id, text);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for but check this library -
http://d3js.org/
its awesome for creating data driven documents and will make your work much easier.
and I think using svg will give you better performance then using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

@TamarG:  to understand why your "i" is always the last i (data.length), I highly recommend a book called "[Async JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1475247362)" by Trevor Burnham.  I've programmed in a lot of languages, and I thought I knew JavaScript until I read this book.  JavaScript event management is non-intuitive - events are managed unlike in any other language I've used.  I didn't get it until I read this book.